# tokenize java camelcase lucene 3

Tags: java, lucene

HI I am using lucene 3

I want to TOKENIZE camelcase words of java e.g. getVariableName into the tokens: get variable name.

I want to store the two ways (with and without camelcase) in the index.

I am indexing by methods as follows.

```
CompilationUnit cu;
        cu = JavaParser.parse(f, "UTF-8");
        MethodVisitior mv;
        mv = new MethodVisitior();
        mv.visit(cu, null);
        ArrayList<MethodDeclaration> methods = mv.methods;

        for (MethodDeclaration method : methods) {
            Document doc = new Document();
            doc.add(new Field("filename", f.getCanonicalPath(), Field.Store.YES, Field.Index.NOT_ANALYZED));
            System.out.println("method " + method);
            String declaration = method.getDeclarationAsString(false, false);
            String name = method.getName();
            int parameters = method.getParameters().size();
            doc.add(new Field("methodDeclaration", f.getName() + "." + declaration, Field.Store.YES,
                    Field.Index.NOT_ANALYZED));
            doc.add(new Field("methodName", name, Field.Store.YES, Field.Index.NOT_ANALYZED));
            doc.add(new Field("parameters", parameters + "", Field.Store.YES, Field.Index.NOT_ANALYZED));
            if (method.getBody() != null)
                doc.add(new Field("contents", declaration + " " + "\n" + method.getBody().toString(), Field.Store.YES,
                        Field.Index.ANALYZED, Field.TermVector.YES));
            indexWriter.updateDocument(new Term("methodDeclaration", f.getName() + "." + declaration), doc);
```

Comment: `WordDelimiterFilter` would be the class to look for. Don't think it was brought into Lucene until 4.0, but you should be able to grab it from Solr 3.6.

Comment: I am using lucene 3

Comment: Right, which is why you would need to pull in the one from Solr 3.6, like I said...

Comment: I dont know how